# Converting XYZ tile coordinate to WMTS

Tags: wmts, mapbox-gl-js, ogc, xyz, tile-map-service

I would like to add a WMTS tile endpoint to Mapbox-GL-JS, which only supports `"XYZ"` or TMS tiling schemes. According to what I understand of the [WMTS specification](http://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/13-082r2/13-082r2.html) the two seem to have the same zoom scheme, so perhaps it's possible to apply some kind of maths to the `X` and `Y`-coordinates to get the right WMTS coordinates.

But I can't figure out what that formula would be - I can't seem to find the right definition.

What is the formular to convert an XYZ tile specifier to WMTS?

Comment: The only difference between the two is a flipped `Y`-coordinate, i.e. for XYZ: the first tile `(0,0)` is on the bottom left / for WMTS: the first tile `(0,0)` is on the top left. You may be interested in this [pyGeoTile](https://github.com/geometalab/pyGeoTile).

Comment: @Taras I thought that was the case between XYZ and TMS - isn't WMTS different?!

Answer (score 2):

There is no general formula, but you can consider XYZ as a special case of WMTS (in the projection of EPSG:3857 with specific origin and offset and zoom order).

If you need an example of WMTSCapabilities.xml file that is identical to XYZ tiling scheme, you can refer to: https://discover.agrc.utah.gov/login/path/dragon-visitor-honey-perfume/wmts/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml.

(In case of link rot)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Capabilities xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wmts/1.0" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wmts/1.0   ../wmtsGetCapabilities_response.xsd" version="1.0.0">
  <ows:ServiceIdentification>
    <ows:Title>utah imagery - WMTS</ows:Title>
    <ows:Abstract><![CDATA[This imagery service is provided by Google as part of a license agreement with the State of Utah. The imagery in this service is typically no more than 3 years old.]]></ows:Abstract>
    <ows:ServiceType>OGC WMTS</ows:ServiceType>
    <ows:ServiceTypeVersion>1.0.0</ows:ServiceTypeVersion>
    <ows:Fees>none</ows:Fees>
    <ows:AccessConstraints>none</ows:AccessConstraints>
  </ows:ServiceIdentification>
  <ows:OperationsMetadata>
    <ows:Operation name="GetCapabilities">
      <ows:DCP>
        <ows:HTTP>
          <ows:Get xlink:href="https://discover.agrc.utah.gov/login/path/dragon-visitor-honey-perfume/wmts/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml">
            <ows:Constraint name="GetEncoding">
              <ows:AllowedValues>
                <ows:Value>RESTful</ows:Value>
              </ows:AllowedValues>
            </ows:Constraint>
          </ows:Get>
          <ows:Get xlink:href="https://discover.agrc.utah.gov/login/path/dragon-visitor-honey-perfume/wmts?">
            <ows:Constraint name="GetEncoding">
              <ows:AllowedValues>
                <ows:Value>KVP</ows:Value>
              </ows:AllowedValues>
            </ows:Constraint>
          </ows:Get>
        </ows:HTTP>
      </ows:DCP>
    </ows:Operation>
    <ows:Operation name="GetTile">
      <ows:DCP>
        <ows:HTTP>
          <ows:Get xlink:href="https://discover.agrc.utah.gov/login/path/dragon-visitor-honey-perfume/wmts?">
            <ows:Constraint name="GetEncoding">
              <ows:AllowedValues>
                <ows:Value>KVP</ows:Value>
              </ows:AllowedValues>
            </ows:Constraint>
          </ows:Get>
        </ows:HTTP>
      </ows:DCP>
    </ows:Operation>
  </ows:OperationsMetadata>
  <Contents>
    <Layer>
      <ows:Title>Basemap-Address_Points</ows:Title>
      <ows:Abstract><![CDATA[]]></ows:Abstract>
      <ows:BoundingBox crs="EPSG:3857">
        <ows:LowerCorner>-13912762.14035464 3620057.659585941</ows:LowerCorner>
        <ows:UpperCorner>-11300450.261680456 6330208.934465155</ows:UpperCorner>
      </ows:BoundingBox>
      <ows:WGS84BoundingBox>
        <ows:LowerCorner>-124.98046875 30.9022247051714</ows:LowerCorner>
        <ows:UpperCorner>-101.513671875 49.32512199104</ows:UpperCorner>
      </ows:WGS84BoundingBox>
      <ows:Identifier>address_points_basemap</ows:Identifier>
      <Style>
        <ows:Identifier>default</ows:Identifier>
      </Style>
        <Format>image/png</Format>
      <TileMatrixSetLink>
        <TileMatrixSet>0to19</TileMatrixSet>
           <TileMatrixLimits>
            <TileMatrix>0to19:00</TileMatrix>
            <MinTileRow>0</MinTileRow>
            <MaxTileRow>0</MaxTileRow>
            <MinTileCol>0</MinTileCol>
            <MaxTileCol>0</MaxTileCol>
          </TileMatrixLimits>
           <TileMatrixLimits>
            <TileMatrix>0to19:01</TileMatrix>
            <MinTileRow>0</MinTileRow>
            <MaxTileRow>0</MaxTileRow>
            <MinTileCol>0</MinTileCol>
            <MaxTileCol>0</MaxTileCol>
          </TileMatrixLimits>
           <TileMatrixLimits>
            <TileMatrix>0to19:02</TileMatrix>
            <MinTileRow>0</MinTileRow>
            <MaxTileRow>0</MaxTileRow>
            <MinTileCol>1</MinTileCol>
            <MaxTileCol>1</MaxTileCol>
          </TileMatrixLimits>
           <TileMatrixLimits>
            <TileMatrix>0to19:03</TileMatrix>
            <MinTileRow>1</MinTileRow>
            <MaxTileRow>1</MaxTileRow>
            <MinTileCol>2</MinTileCol>
            <MaxTileCol>3</MaxTileCol>
          </TileMatrixLimits>
           <TileMatrixLimits>
            <TileMatrix>0to19:04</TileMatrix>
            <MinTileRow>2</MinTileRow>
            <MaxTileRow>3</MaxTileRow>
            <MinTileCol>5</MinTileCol>
            <MaxTileCol>6</MaxTileCol>
          </TileMatrixLimits>
           <TileMatrixLimits>
            <TileMatrix>0to19:05</TileMatrix>
            <MinTileRow>4</MinTileRow>
            <MaxTileRow>6</MaxTileRow>
            <MinTileCol>10</MinTileCol>
            <MaxTileCol>13</MaxTileCol>
          </TileMatrixLimits>
           <TileMatrixLimits>
            <TileMatrix>0to19:06</TileMatrix>
            <MinTileRow>9</MinTileRow>
            <MaxTileRow>13</MaxTileRow>
            <MinTileCol>21</MinTileCol>
            <MaxTileCol>26</MaxTileCol>
          </TileMatrixLimits>
           <TileMatrixLimits>
            <TileMatrix>0to19:07</TileMatrix>
            <MinTileRow>19</MinTileRow>
            <MaxTileRow>27</MaxTileRow>
            <MinTileCol>43</MinTileCol>
            <MaxTileCol>52</MaxTileCol>
          </TileMatrixLimits>
           <TileMatrixLimits>
            <TileMatrix>0to19:08</TileMatrix>
            <MinTileRow>39</MinTileRow>
            <MaxTileRow>55</MaxTileRow>
            <MinTileCol>87</MinTileCol>
            <MaxTileCol>104</MaxTileCol>
          </TileMatrixLimits>
           <TileMatrixLimits>
            <TileMatrix>0to19:09</TileMatrix>
            <MinTileRow>78</MinTileRow>
            <MaxTileRow>111</MaxTileRow>
            <MinTileCol>175</MinTileCol>
            <MaxTileCol>209</MaxTileCol>
          </TileMatrixLimits>
           <TileMatrixLimits>
            <TileMatrix>0to19:10</TileMatrix>
            <MinTileRow>156</MinTileRow>
            <MaxTileRow>223</MaxTileRow>
            <MinTileCol>350</MinTileCol>
            <MaxTileCol>419</MaxTileCol>
          </TileMatrixLimits>
           <TileMatrixLimits>
            <TileMatrix>0to19:11</TileMatrix>
            <MinTileRow>313</MinTileRow>
            <MaxTileRow>446</MaxTileRow>
            <MinTileCol>700</MinTileCol>
            <MaxTileCol>838</MaxTileCol>
          </TileMatrixLimits>
           <TileMatrixLimits>
            <TileMatrix>0to19:12</TileMatrix>
            <MinTileRow>626</MinTileRow>
            <MaxTileRow>892</MaxTileRow>
            <MinTileCol>1401</MinTileCol>
            <MaxTileCol>1677</MaxTileCol>
          </TileMatrixLimits>
           <TileMatrixLimits>
            <TileMatrix>0to19:13</TileMatrix>
            <MinTileRow>1252</MinTileRow>
            <MaxTileRow>1785</MaxTileRow>
            <MinTileCol>2802</MinTileCol>
            <MaxTileCol>3355</MaxTileCol>
          </TileMatrixLimits>
           <TileMatrixLimits>
            <TileMatrix>0to19:14</TileMatrix>
            <MinTileRow>2504</MinTileRow>
            <MaxTileRow>3571</MaxTileRow>
            <MinTileCol>5604</MinTileCol>
            <MaxTileCol>6711</MaxTileCol>
          </TileMatrixLimits>
           <TileMatrixLimits>
            <TileMatrix>0to19:15</TileMatrix>
            <MinTileRow>5008</MinTileRow>
            <MaxTileRow>7143</MaxTileRow>
            <MinTileCol>11208</MinTileCol>
            <MaxTileCol>13423</MaxTileCol>
          </TileMatrixLimits>
           <TileMatrixLimits>
            <TileMatrix>0to19:16</TileMatrix>
            <MinTileRow>10016</MinTileRow>
            <MaxTileRow>14287</MaxTileRow>
            <MinTileCol>22416</MinTileCol>
            <MaxTileCol>26847</MaxTileCol>
          </TileMatrixLimits>
           <TileMatrixLimits>
            <TileMatrix>0to19:17</TileMatrix>
            <MinTileRow>20032</MinTileRow>
            <MaxTileRow>28575</MaxTileRow>
            <MinTileCol>44832</MinTileCol>
            <MaxTileCol>53695</MaxTileCol>
          </TileMatrixLimits>
           <TileMatrixLimits>
            <TileMatrix>0to19:18</TileMatrix>
            <MinTileRow>40064</MinTileRow>
            <MaxTileRow>57151</MaxTileRow>
            <MinTileCol>89664</MinTileCol>
            <MaxTileCol>107391</MaxTileCol>
          </TileMatrixLimits>
           <TileMatrixLimits>
            <TileMatrix>0to19:19</TileMatrix>
            <MinTileRow>80128</MinTileRow>
            <MaxTileRow>114303</MaxTileRow>
            <MinTileCol>179328</MinTileCol>
            <MaxTileCol>214783</MaxTileCol>
          </TileMatrixLimits>
      </TileMatrixSetLink>
      <ResourceURL format="image/png"
      resourceType="tile"
      template="https://discover.agrc.utah.gov/login/path/dragon-visitor-honey-perfume/wmts?SERVICE=WMTS&amp;VERSION=1.0.0&amp;REQUEST=GetTile&amp;LAYER=address_points_basemap&amp;STYLE=default&amp;FORMAT=image/png&amp;TILEMATRIXSET={TileMatrixSet}&amp;TILEMATRIX={TileMatrix}&amp;TILEROW={TileRow}&amp;TILECOL={TileCol}"/>
    </Layer>
    
    <!-- omitted -->

    <TileMatrixSet>
      <ows:Identifier>0to19</ows:Identifier>
      <ows:SupportedCRS>EPSG:3857</ows:SupportedCRS>
      <TileMatrix>
        <ows:Identifier>0to19:00</ows:Identifier>
        <ScaleDenominator>559082264.029</ScaleDenominator>
        <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.3428 20037508.3428</TopLeftCorner>
        <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
        <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
        <MatrixWidth>1</MatrixWidth>
        <MatrixHeight>1</MatrixHeight>
      </TileMatrix>
      <TileMatrix>
        <ows:Identifier>0to19:01</ows:Identifier>
        <ScaleDenominator>279541132.014</ScaleDenominator>
        <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.3428 20037508.3428</TopLeftCorner>
        <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
        <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
        <MatrixWidth>2</MatrixWidth>
        <MatrixHeight>2</MatrixHeight>
      </TileMatrix>
      <TileMatrix>
        <ows:Identifier>0to19:02</ows:Identifier>
        <ScaleDenominator>139770566.007</ScaleDenominator>
        <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.3428 20037508.3428</TopLeftCorner>
        <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
        <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
        <MatrixWidth>4</MatrixWidth>
        <MatrixHeight>4</MatrixHeight>
      </TileMatrix>
      <TileMatrix>
        <ows:Identifier>0to19:03</ows:Identifier>
        <ScaleDenominator>69885283.0036</ScaleDenominator>
        <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.3428 20037508.3428</TopLeftCorner>
        <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
        <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
        <MatrixWidth>8</MatrixWidth>
        <MatrixHeight>8</MatrixHeight>
      </TileMatrix>
      <TileMatrix>
        <ows:Identifier>0to19:04</ows:Identifier>
        <ScaleDenominator>34942641.5018</ScaleDenominator>
        <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.3428 20037508.3428</TopLeftCorner>
        <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
        <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
        <MatrixWidth>16</MatrixWidth>
        <MatrixHeight>16</MatrixHeight>
      </TileMatrix>
      <TileMatrix>
        <ows:Identifier>0to19:05</ows:Identifier>
        <ScaleDenominator>17471320.7509</ScaleDenominator>
        <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.3428 20037508.3428</TopLeftCorner>
        <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
        <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
        <MatrixWidth>32</MatrixWidth>
        <MatrixHeight>32</MatrixHeight>
      </TileMatrix>
      <TileMatrix>
        <ows:Identifier>0to19:06</ows:Identifier>
        <ScaleDenominator>8735660.37545</ScaleDenominator>
        <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.3428 20037508.3428</TopLeftCorner>
        <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
        <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
        <MatrixWidth>64</MatrixWidth>
        <MatrixHeight>64</MatrixHeight>
      </TileMatrix>
      <TileMatrix>
        <ows:Identifier>0to19:07</ows:Identifier>
        <ScaleDenominator>4367830.18772</ScaleDenominator>
        <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.3428 20037508.3428</TopLeftCorner>
        <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
        <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
        <MatrixWidth>128</MatrixWidth>
        <MatrixHeight>128</MatrixHeight>
      </TileMatrix>
      <TileMatrix>
        <ows:Identifier>0to19:08</ows:Identifier>
        <ScaleDenominator>2183915.09386</ScaleDenominator>
        <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.3428 20037508.3428</TopLeftCorner>
        <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
        <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
        <MatrixWidth>256</MatrixWidth>
        <MatrixHeight>256</MatrixHeight>
      </TileMatrix>
      <TileMatrix>
        <ows:Identifier>0to19:09</ows:Identifier>
        <ScaleDenominator>1091957.54693</ScaleDenominator>
        <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.3428 20037508.3428</TopLeftCorner>
        <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
        <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
        <MatrixWidth>512</MatrixWidth>
        <MatrixHeight>512</MatrixHeight>
      </TileMatrix>
      <TileMatrix>
        <ows:Identifier>0to19:10</ows:Identifier>
        <ScaleDenominator>545978.773466</ScaleDenominator>
        <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.3428 20037508.3428</TopLeftCorner>
        <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
        <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
        <MatrixWidth>1024</MatrixWidth>
        <MatrixHeight>1024</MatrixHeight>
      </TileMatrix>
      <TileMatrix>
        <ows:Identifier>0to19:11</ows:Identifier>
        <ScaleDenominator>272989.386733</ScaleDenominator>
        <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.3428 20037508.3428</TopLeftCorner>
        <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
        <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
        <MatrixWidth>2048</MatrixWidth>
        <MatrixHeight>2048</MatrixHeight>
      </TileMatrix>
      <TileMatrix>
        <ows:Identifier>0to19:12</ows:Identifier>
        <ScaleDenominator>136494.693366</ScaleDenominator>
        <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.3428 20037508.3428</TopLeftCorner>
        <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
        <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
        <MatrixWidth>4096</MatrixWidth>
        <MatrixHeight>4096</MatrixHeight>
      </TileMatrix>
      <TileMatrix>
        <ows:Identifier>0to19:13</ows:Identifier>
        <ScaleDenominator>68247.3466832</ScaleDenominator>
        <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.3428 20037508.3428</TopLeftCorner>
        <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
        <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
        <MatrixWidth>8192</MatrixWidth>
        <MatrixHeight>8192</MatrixHeight>
      </TileMatrix>
      <TileMatrix>
        <ows:Identifier>0to19:14</ows:Identifier>
        <ScaleDenominator>34123.6733416</ScaleDenominator>
        <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.3428 20037508.3428</TopLeftCorner>
        <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
        <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
        <MatrixWidth>16384</MatrixWidth>
        <MatrixHeight>16384</MatrixHeight>
      </TileMatrix>
      <TileMatrix>
        <ows:Identifier>0to19:15</ows:Identifier>
        <ScaleDenominator>17061.8366708</ScaleDenominator>
        <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.3428 20037508.3428</TopLeftCorner>
        <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
        <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
        <MatrixWidth>32768</MatrixWidth>
        <MatrixHeight>32768</MatrixHeight>
      </TileMatrix>
      <TileMatrix>
        <ows:Identifier>0to19:16</ows:Identifier>
        <ScaleDenominator>8530.9183354</ScaleDenominator>
        <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.3428 20037508.3428</TopLeftCorner>
        <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
        <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
        <MatrixWidth>65536</MatrixWidth>
        <MatrixHeight>65536</MatrixHeight>
      </TileMatrix>
      <TileMatrix>
        <ows:Identifier>0to19:17</ows:Identifier>
        <ScaleDenominator>4265.4591677</ScaleDenominator>
        <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.3428 20037508.3428</TopLeftCorner>
        <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
        <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
        <MatrixWidth>131072</MatrixWidth>
        <MatrixHeight>131072</MatrixHeight>
      </TileMatrix>
      <TileMatrix>
        <ows:Identifier>0to19:18</ows:Identifier>
        <ScaleDenominator>2132.72958385</ScaleDenominator>
        <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.3428 20037508.3428</TopLeftCorner>
        <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
        <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
        <MatrixWidth>262144</MatrixWidth>
        <MatrixHeight>262144</MatrixHeight>
      </TileMatrix>
      <TileMatrix>
        <ows:Identifier>0to19:19</ows:Identifier>
        <ScaleDenominator>1066.36479192</ScaleDenominator>
        <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.3428 20037508.3428</TopLeftCorner>
        <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
        <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
        <MatrixWidth>524288</MatrixWidth>
        <MatrixHeight>524288</MatrixHeight>
      </TileMatrix>
      
      <!-- omitted -->
    </TileMatrixSet>
  </Contents>
</Capabilities>
```

Bear in mind most existing WMTS tilesets would not coincide with XYZ (which is much more simplified), as WMTS specification allows for a lot of flexibility (e.g. different origins at different zoom levels).